# Ajax, PHP and MySQL and append data in a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm building a page that looks like the following:

[image: events]

What's the **goal**:

- When the user clicks in the input box and selects a particular date, it runs a php script that searches the database for records with that specific date and appends them in a specific div.

***What have I done so far:***

1. HTML and CSS:

> ```
> <div class="input-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
>       <input type="text" class="form-control date">
>       <span class="input-group-addon calendar-date-picker">
>            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
>       </span>
>   </div>
> ```

(...)

> ```
> this is cool :<p> <?php print_r($_POST);?> </p>
> <div class="results-ajax"></div>
> ```

. *It uses 'date' in the class of the input for opening the datepicker calendar*.

. *It has a specific div with one class 'results-ajax' where the input generated by the script should be displayed at*.

2. JS and Ajax:

> ```
> jQuery(function($) {
>
>   $(".date").datepicker({
>     onSelect: function(dateText) {
>       display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
>       $(this).change();
>     }
>   }).on("change", function() {
>     display("Got change event from field");
>     $.ajax({
>       type: "POST",
>       url: 'events_script.php',
>       data: ({dates: this.value}),
>       success: function(data) {
>         $(".results-ajax").load(data);
>         alert(data);
>       }
>   });
> });
>   function display(msg) {
>     $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
>   }
>
> });
> ```

. *Once new date gets picked up, **the results are shown bellow under Outcomes**. .*

. *The Ajax call is posting in events_script.php*.

3. PHP (*events_script.php*)

> ```
> <?php
> include 'config/config.php';
> include 'libraries/database.php';
>
>     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
>     print_r($_POST);
>     echo $_POST[dates];
>     $dias= $_POST[dates];
> ```
>
> //Make database query
>
> ```
> $sql = "SELECT *
>         FROM events
>         RIGHT OUTER JOIN companies ON companies.companyID = events.Ref_ID
>         WHERE events.Start_Date= '$dias%'
>         ORDER BY events.Start_Date DESC";
>
> $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
> if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
> ```
>
> // output data of each row
>
> ```
>   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
>       echo '<p>'.print_r($_POST).'</p>';
>   }
> ```
>
> `} else { echo 'No results found.'; }  } ?>`

**Outcomes**:

**1.** The result of the JS display and append

[image: events-result1]

**2.** The result of the alert in Ajax (using the PHP script):

[image: events-result2]

**Problems:**

1. Why is it the data alerted not being loaded in the div with the class 'results-ajax', as commanded in Ajax?

I've tested also using appendTo instead of load and also didn't work.

Also,

2. . Is there any step missing/wrong in the procedure in order for the data posted to be recognized by the database, once in the query ('**$dias%**')?

Because rn displays 'No results found' (as you can see in the alert), and there's records in the database with that specific date.

(it happened so many times that the value is exactly like the one in the database but because one was string and the other date, nothing was being displayed - just to make sure this is not one of those cases)

**To note:**

No errors in the PHP error log.

In the console, there's this error: GET example.com/Array( 404 (Not Found). It shows up once the alert box is closed.

Comment: Are you sure that your php script is getting the posted date?

Comment: ok, $('.results-ajax').html(data) solved the first problem

Comment: @tiagoperes make sure your `$dias` is comparing same format with the date column from your table, possible that your date column is not the same format with your `$dias` datepicker has a different default format

Comment: @Shubhranshu yes, it can be seen in the alert box

Comment: @Roljhon can you be more specific?

Comment: why its `$dias%`? is it not `$dias` alone?

Comment: in the db is stored in the following way: Y-M-D h:m:s.
the variable: d/m/y.

Ok, this is the problem.
Any idea in how to fix it?

Comment: in your php script just do like `$newdate = date('Y-m-d h:m:s',strtotime($dias));` then use `$newdate` in your query instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using the following code

1. HTML and CSS:

> ```
> <div class="input-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
>       <input type="text" class="form-control date">
>       <span class="input-group-addon calendar-date-picker">
>            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
>       </span>
>   </div>
> ```

(...)

> ```
> this is cool :<p> <?php print_r($_POST);?> </p>
> <div class="results-ajax"></div>
> ```

. *It uses 'date' in the class of the input for opening the datepicker calendar*.

. *It has a specific div with one class 'results-ajax' where the input generated by the script is displayed at*.

2. JS and Ajax:

> ```
> jQuery(function($) {
>
>   $(".date").datepicker({
>     onSelect: function(dateText) {
>       display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
>       $(this).change();
>     }
>   }).on("change", function() {
>     display("Got change event from field");
>     $.ajax({
>       type: "POST",
>       url: 'events_script.php',
>       data: ({dates: this.value}),
>       success: function(data) {
>         $('.results-ajax').html(data);
>         alert(data);
>       }
>   });
> });
>   function display(msg) {
>     $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
>   }
>
> });
> ```

. *Once new date gets picked up, **the results are shown bellow under Outcomes**. .*

. *The Ajax call is posting in events_script.php*.

3. PHP (*events_script.php*)

> ```
> <?php
> include 'config/config.php';
> include 'libraries/database.php';
>
>     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
>     print_r($_POST);
>     echo $_POST[dates];
>     $dias= $_POST[dates];
>     $mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dias));
> ```
>
> //Make database query
>
> ```
> $sql = "SELECT *
>         FROM events
>         left JOIN companies ON companies.companyID = events.Ref_ID AND companies.Ref_Type = events.Ref_Type
>         WHERE events.Start_Date= '".$mysql_date."'
>         ORDER BY events.Start_Date DESC";
>
> $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
> if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
> ```
>
> // output data of each row
>
> ```
>   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
>       echo '<p>It works!</p>';
>   }
> ```
>
> `} else { echo 'No results found.'; }  } ?>`

**Outcomes**:

**1.** The result of the alert in Ajax (using the PHP script):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date to MySql format, here is how to do it :

```
function date_convert($value,$fromFormat,$toFormat){
    try{
        $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($fromFormat, $value);
        if ($myDateTime)
            return  $myDateTime->format($toFormat);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return '';
    }
}
// this supposes that by 01/03/2017 you're talking about the 1st of Mars
// if you mean the 3rd or January change the from format to : 'm/d/Y'
$dias = date_convert($dias,'d/m/Y','Y-m-d');
```

Comment: make sure you converted the date to YYYY-MM-DD before making the database request

Comment: that doesn't work even if add it before the DB request