# access java script variable value in php and insert into database

Tags: javascript, php

This is my javascript code:

```
var totalPrice=0;
    var x=parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value)||0;
    var e = document.getElementById("currency");
    var value = parseFloat(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    totalPrice=(x*value).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML="<h3>Total Price : "+totalPrice+" "+text+"</h3>";
```

this is my html code:

```
<div id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice"></div>
```

i want to access this variable var total price value in a php variable.

Comment: In what way? Are you submitting a form? Do you expect to get feedback from your PHP script? Have you learned about form submission and AJAX?

Comment: Check my [previous challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908768/ajax-php-and-mysql-and-append-data-in-a-page), it might solve your doubts.